# Вызов программы для обработки адреса

Tags: android, android-intent

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q= г.Барнаул, ул. Г.Исакова 200"));
startActivity(intent);
```

При запуске этого android предлагает выбрать либо google maps либо yandex карты, у меня еще установлен 2гис, почему его нельзя выбрать, не думаю что в приложении 2гис не предусмотрено такое? Либо по другому - какую ссылку генерировать чтобы открыть сайт 2гис с этом адресом?

на сайте 2гиса чот не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если гео-запрос оформленный в виде `Intent` идет в формате [Geo URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI), то [согласно документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) вызывается гео приложение (по умолчанию Google Maps).

В частном случае, опять же [согласно документации](http://api.2gis.ru/doc/geo/search/) 2ГИС ни фига не поддерживает Geo URI - что в общем то странно, поскольку поддержать Geo URI вроде бы просто, достаточно прописать в манифесте декларацию о том, что есть активити обрабатывающий Geo URI:

```
<activity android:name=".2GisActivity">
  <intent-filter>               
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="geo"/>            
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

А в самом активити распарсить Geo URI - что совсем уж тривиально и всё.

В общем загадка.

**Update**

Да, касательно собсно самого вопроса - если уж так охота запускать именно 2ГИС, то надо написать простенькое приложение (типа бриджа/моста) из 1-го активити, которая декларирует, что она умеет обрабатывать Geo URI (как описано выше) далее запускает 2ГИС уже через запрос в формате: `http://catalog.api.2gis.ru/geo/search` (см. документацию по API 2ГИС выше)